# Laravel - Get a data from a form

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm working on a form (without MySQL for the moment) in order to get a data from an input with a confirm message page like "Congratulations $pseudo, your subscribe is successful".

**Problem** : I can't display the data what I inserted into my form.

**Guideline** : I think the problem is on my controller in the postUsers method but I don't know how to resolve it.

Here is my form (**subscribe.blade.php**)

```
@extends('template')

@section('contenu')
<div class="container">
<h1>Inscription</h1>
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'users/confirm']) !!}
    <div class="form-group has-feedback {!! $errors->has('pseudo') ? 'has-error' : '' !!}">
        <label for="pseudo">Pseudonyme</label>
        {!! Form::text('pseudo', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'id_pseudo', 'placeholder' => 'Votre pseudonyme']) !!}
        {!! $errors->first('pseudo', '<small class="help-block">:message</small>') !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::submit('Inscription', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is the confirm page (**confirm.blade.php**)

```
@extends('template')

@section('contenu')
<br>
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Validation</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           Féicitations<?php Request::input('pseudo')?>, vous êtes inscrit sur le site ! Vous pouvez dès à présent vous connecter.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is my routes (**routes.php**)

```
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@getUsers');
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@postUsers');
```

And the controller (**UsersController.php**)

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
public function getUsers(){ 
    return view('confirm');
}

public function postUsers(Request $request){ 
    return 'Le nom est ' . $request->input('pseudo');
}
}
```

I hope it can helps you to resolve this little problem, I'm following a course about laravel and this framework is facinating for me ^^

Thank you a lot for taking time on my problem. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `POST` instead of `GET` when you're submitting form. Also, you're using wrong URL, so try to change this:

```
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@postUsers');
```

to this:

```
Route::post('users/confirm', 'UsersController@postUsers');
```

If you want to display data in `confirm` view, do something like this:

```
public function postUsers(Request $request){ 
    return view('confirm', ['pseudo' => $request->pseudo]);
}
```

and view:

```
....
<div class="panel-body">
    Féicitations {{ $pseudo }}, vous êtes inscrit sur le site ! Vous pouvez dès à présent vous connecter.
</div>
....
```

Comment: Thank you, it will help me for other forms. I just need to display my input with the confirm.blade.php

Comment: It works but I need to understand. Why use an array as a second parameter on the postUsers method ?

Comment: Second parameter is data which you pass to a view from a controller. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: I understand, so thank you for your expertise, it helps me a lot.